# DateTime.Now as file name

Tags: c#

I would like to give a document I've created programmatically a name which contains the returned value of `DateTime.Now.ToString();`

The trial failed when ":" symbol is a content of the file name.

Any Idea?

Comment: Then replace the `:` with something else?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Show your work first.. Also you can read [FAQ] and [ask] as a start..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid problemw with culture like this

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMdd-HH-mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

also you can try out

```
string n = string.Format("typeoffile-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.ext",
        DateTime.Now);
```

---

try this will work for you

```
String.Replace(".","_")
```

turn in

```
   DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(".","_")
```

Comment: Who down-voted this? It is a perfectly valid answer?

Comment: It's not a very solid solution since the output of `DateTime.Now.ToString()` is dependant on Culture and it may not just be a `.` causing issues for Culture XX-yy. I didn't downvote though.

Answer (score 4):

I would specify a format for `DateTime.ToString()`, for example:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") //results in "20131127103249"
```

If you want to go the `String.Replace` route, I suggest leveraging a useful method called `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()`:

```
string s = DateTime.Now.ToString();
foreach (char c in Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) // replace all invalid characters with an underscore
{
    s = s.Replace(c, '_');
}
```

Or, if you're into the whole brevity thing, you can do the same thing in a one-liner using LINQ:

```
var s = new String(DateTime.Now.ToString().Select(ch => Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Any(invalid => invalid == ch) ? '_' : ch).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the replace function to replace the `:` with for example `_`

```
DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(":","_");
```

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString()` could also produce other characters that are invalid for filenames, e.g. `/`

Comment: @StephanBauer Thanks! I just saw it in the other answers. I wasn't aware of that :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try removing the ":" symbol, i.e. filename will be:

20131127_0530

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyddMM_HHmm")
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be using the custom ToString method specify a formatter i.e:

DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") - shows daymonthyear